# How do I create a custom add media button modal?

Tags: plugins, media, api, buttons, media-modal

I've created a custom media button for the admin in editing posts, but am having trouble figuring out how to create a view for the modal. I'm not trying to insert uploaded media; I'm trying to allow the user to search and insert existing videos via the API.

I've been looking at thickbox and media-views.js as examples, but have been having trouble with the configuration. Do I have to include an additional file for this view in wp-admin? Do I place a partial in the footer?

I've got the following so far.

```
add_action('media_buttons', 'add_media_button_wizard', 12);


public static function add_media_button_wizard()
{
    echo '<a href="display-code.php" class="button thickbox" title="Sample Title"> Sample Button</a>';
}
```

I'm really new to Wordpress plugin development, so if someone could point me in the right direction, that would be great. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can inspire from this tutorial here:
http://www.sitepoint.com/adding-a-media-button-to-the-content-editor/

For videos you can change the library type to 'video':

```
function open_media_window() {
    var window = wp.media({
        title: 'Insert a media',
        library: {type: 'video'},
        multiple: false,
        button: {text: 'Insert'}
    });
}
```

Hope this helps.